# Redis.set not saving key with underscores or hyphens, Redis.get returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

As the title suggests, I'm using the Redis gem and here is the output:

```
2.2.2 :011 > $redis = Redis.connect
 => #<Redis client v3.2.1 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0> 
2.2.2 :012 > $redis.set("max-tag-id", "hi")
 => "OK" 
2.2.2 :013 > $redis.get("max-tax-id")
 => nil 
2.2.2 :014 > $redis.set("max_tag_id", "hi")
 => "OK" 
2.2.2 :015 > $redis.get("max_tax_id")
 => nil 
2.2.2 :016 > $redis.set("maxtagid", "hi")
 => "OK" 
2.2.2 :018 > $redis.get("maxtagid")
 => "hi"
```

Why is this??

Comment: Looking into it. If you open a direct connection to redis, the keys are there with values. Also if you use a key named 'key-dash' then it works. Why 'max-tag-id' can't be read I'm not sure.

Comment: And now I can't reproduce what you're experiencing at all (but I did at one point)

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom that's bizarre..

Comment: you can use redis-cli monitor to see what gets to redis http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR probably its ruby/Redis gem related

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get nil you're getting "max_tax_id" you never set that key. You set "max_tag_id"